# Function that provides callback for promise or non-promise

Tags: typescript

Below I created a `use` function that wraps a promise or non-promise, providing the a value callback all-while preserving the original function type.

```
type ThenArg<T> = T extends Promise<infer U> ? U : T
type Func = (...args: any[]) => any

type RelatedThen<PP, V> = PP extends Promise<infer U> ? Promise<V> : V


function isPromise(obj: any) {
    return !!obj && (typeof obj === 'object' || typeof obj === 'function') && typeof obj.then === 'function'
}

function use<A extends Func, G>(fn: A, callback: (e: Error | null, a: ThenArg<ReturnType<A>>) => G) {
    return (...args: Parameters<A>): RelatedThen<ReturnType<A>, G> => {
        try {
            const v = fn(...args as any[])
            if (isPromise(v)) {
                return v.then((r: any) => callback(null, r)).catch((e: Error) => callback(e, undefined as ThenArg<ReturnType<A>>))
            }
            return callback(null, v) as RelatedThen<ReturnType<A>, G>
        } catch (e) {
            return callback(e, undefined as ThenArg<ReturnType<A>>) as unknown as RelatedThen<ReturnType<A>, G>
        }
    }
}


const p = async () => 'hi'
const n = () => 'hi'

const a = use(p, (value) => { 
    return value + ' mom'
})

const b = use(n, (value) => { 
    return value + ' dad'
})

a().then(console.log)
console.log(b())
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=38&pc=17#code/C4TwDgpgBAKgFhAdgQQE4HMA8MB8UC8sUEAHsEgCYDOUACqgPYC2AllRJi4gGYSpQBVPAH5BUAFywAUKEhQAYgFdEAYwJQAFADodAQwxVJuxCADaAXQCUBPMZBSZ4aACUIAG13kK8JJlq0AGigANTxCf2IyShp6ZjYOLl5+IShRWNZ2TFCJEIcpbmUVYBYGRCg2dPiNBgAjACsjE2sAbykodqhUCGBFVDKAQn7auqgAMlHNWQgGbihhgnxCAHJhiCKlqAAfTagpmbn6heWC1WLSpetx3ad94a1gBDLF48KzxCWpAF8HE6KSssUmWQkXIiGoCkKQQA4jgNNxEJJkEEVLo3G4aroVABrSQaCCSACiqEY-B2iEUaKCukkPhQGEwrh6fRgTkwyBwOGs+DwUJabQ6XSZZW0egMklo+l0TG6fCobM5klcHi8tIZ3V6iBZkHl0LCeFaHUNu1QICgBqNFpUpSowCgADd1PCRVp9OgaLp3SYLJZ+RbDSxZhoKowMhANHbLHy-dHOuq+vb7o8NBpUI0QFy8Ci0RjsRpyZTOpGtCjgCo4Mn8VAiSSM1As+jMVi8UFlBQINwuBAKFAPbBHmgsIyNVqOOzOT6Yx1vpP2oKNXXUQ3c-m3EEIz2aErPF3VUPmaz2brfUbPgvS3BNBAozO5-H6zmmxAW2D253u73aQO1UKR-LORuoGULFEAYAB3Mpey3FVHm-YcDxwI9o2nKcvjyK1EBtKAwHUD0QFUTRayWOAWA+dDMKeAibCgIiSIcMjbV0dRATDMAgnDVFFCvKjmigY9bzKO0OOgABqaioCYZgPk+H0pHoqAaiY9g8zYwS3E42seL4uMBKEqBRI2ChdAoKSZN0DRLETJANDIhg3AgLQ3AYdAfRsuyHKcjQanMywgA)